# Create View That Overlays The Theme When Field Clicked

Tags: views, 6, javascript

Hello i like the feature that ive seen on a few themes where it lets you have an overlay button top left and when you click it it overlays the whole screen with a grid or in my case a picture. Here;s a video explaining more if you dont mind. Its just brief.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwXV20VJAr8&feature=youtu.be

I would like to create a View and let the items on it have the same function as this overlay button. Im sure it would be possible. I could do most of it barr the action of clicking a view title (button) and making html overlay.

Actually there sounds like there will be a module to do this. I would rather avoid if i could. Maybe some jquery or something wuld be easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect like this for example:

- You put a view block on top (which will overlay the other content) and put the other content below, position them on top of each other with position: absolute.
- Then create a button and position it however you prefer.
- Use jQuery .click() with this button (http://api.jquery.com/click/) to hide and show your view block. One possible solution is that on click, you examine if the view block has a "hidden" CSS class (for example). If it has "hidden" on click, you remove the class with .removeClass("hidden"), if it doesn't have the class, you add it with .addClass("hidden").
- CSS styling should be like this: .hidden{ display: none; }

Comment: Thanks Balint i will need to get to look at this in a few days as im snowed over.